# Using Strings to Identify Sequence of Column Names in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am currently try to use pre-defined strings in order to identify multiple column names in R.
To be more explicit, I am using the `ave` function to create identification variables for subgroups of a dataframe. The twist is that I want the identification variables to be flexible, in such a manner that I would just pass it as a generic string.

A sample code would be:

```
ids = with(df,ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),subcolumn1,subcolumn2,subcolumn3,FUN=seq_along))
```

I would like to run this code in the following fashion (code below does not work as expected):

```
subColumnsString = c("subcolumn1","subcolumn2","subcolumn3")
ids = with(df,ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),subColumnsString ,FUN=seq_along))
```

I tried something with eval, but still did not work:

```
subColumnsString = c("subcolumn1","subcolumn2","subcolumn3")
ids = with(df,ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),eval(parse(text=subColumnsString)),FUN=seq_along))
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT: Working code example of what I want:

```
df = mtcars
id_names = c("vs","am")
idDF_correct = transform(df,idItem = as.numeric(interaction(vs,am)))
idDF_wrong = cbind(df,ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),df[id_names],FUN=seq_along))
```

Note how in idDF_correct, the unique combinations are correctly mapped into unique values of idItem. In idDF_wrong this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think this achieves what you requested. Here I use the `mtcars` dataset that ships with R:

```
subColumnsString <- c("cyl","gear")

ids = with(mtcars, ave(rep(1,nrow(mtcars)), mtcars[subColumnsString], FUN=seq_along))
```

Just index your data.frame using the sub columns which returns a list that naturally works with `ave`

**EDIT**

```
ids = ave(rep(1,nrow(mtcars)), mtcars[subColumnsString], FUN=seq_along)
```

You can omit the `with` and just call plain 'ol `ave`, as G. Grothendieck, stated and you should also use their answer as it is much more general.

Comment: The with is not really used so it could be omitted.

Comment: For some reason this is not creating the identification number as expected (the number repeats itself for different subgroups). My identification variables are strings, but that should not be a problem, should it? When using interaction, it works just fine: idDF = transform(df,id = as.numeric(interaction(subCol1,subCol2,subCol3)))

Comment: An example of your expected output would help.

Comment: Edited the question with a mwe.

Answer (score 1):

This defines a function whose arguments are:

- `data`, the input data frame
- `by`, a character vector of column names in `data`
- `fun`, a function to use in `ave`

Code--

```
Ave <- function(data, by, fun = seq_along) {
   do.call(function(...) ave(rep(1, nrow(data)), ..., FUN = fun), data[by])
}

# test 
Ave(CO2, c("Plant", "Treatment"), seq_along)
```

giving:

```
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
[39] 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
[77] 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```